# NullpointerException while initializing variables in contentprovider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

Hi i am trying to solve this from quite sometime but not able to success

I am trying to initialize the variables in content provider as below

```
public static String rb_radio ;
    public static String im_radio ;
    static {
        rb_radio = context.getResources().getString(R.string.kgs);
        im_radio = context.getResources().getString(R.string.grams);
    }

    public AerProvider(Context ctx) {
        super(ctx);
        context = ctx;
```

i am setting rb_radio values for the resource folder as you can see
but i am getting null pointer exception,below is my stack trace

```
10-09 16:38:40.265: E/AndroidRuntime(4114): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-09 16:38:40.265: E/AndroidRuntime(4114):at com.in.android.aer.contentprovider.AerProvider.<clinit>(AerProvider.java:49)
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

When `rb_radio` is initialized in a static way, `context` does not have a value yet as it will get its value in the constructor, when the object is instantiated.

Try this :

```
public static String rb_radio = null;
public static String im_radio = null;

public AerProvider(Context ctx) {
    super(ctx);
    context = ctx;
    if (rb_radio == null) rb_radio = context.getResources().getString(R.string.kgs);
    if (im_radio == null) im_radio = context.getResources().getString(R.string.grams);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code in your `static` initializer is too early to run at static initialization phase. For example, the instance variable `context` is not yet initialized.

Move the code in your `static { ... }` block to `onCreate()` in the proider.

Also note that content providers should not have a constructor that takes args, though with this code you should be getting a compile-time error if the class really was a `ContentProvider`.

Comment: cool thank you, how should i get R.string values loaded to my static block when the application starts?

Comment: You can't. Context and resources are only available in and after `onCreate()` in android app/activity/service/whatever lifecycle.